# problem with footnote in xepersian : " Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote"

Tags: errors, footnotes, xepersian

I have problem in using `xepersian` package. When I use footnote, it come with the error `Undefined control sequence \end`
but without `xepersian` it works properly.

I use MiKTeX 2.9

---

here is the code

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xepersian}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}

    \includegraphics{../Pictures/tehran}

    \huge This is My First work!

    \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

and here is the error

```
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \small By me\footnote{dfgdtjk}
    Undefined control sequence \end{document}
    Overfull \hbox (0.99916pt too wide) in paragraph
    Overfull \hbox (172.67282pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: I think we will need to see more of the log file here: for me, the only issue is that I don't have the graphic you use (which I get round using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce your problem. Using version 12.8 of xepersian with TeXLive 2013 pretest, I get no error.

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup Miktex has still version v12.7 and I get a lot of error messages that `\Umathcode` is undefined. In TeXlive 2012 (which has an older version) there is no problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It is because MiKTeX ships an old XeTeX binary.

Comment: @PersianTeXGroup the example seems to work when I add `\let\Umathcode\XeTeXmathcode  \let\Umathchardef\XeTeXmathchardef`. Perhaps the package should make a suitable test to avoid to break with older engines (and perhaps make a feature request so that miktex updates the binary.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Indeed in the previous versions of xepersian, something like that existed but miktex should update its xetex binary.

Answer (score 3):

The example seems to work when I add `\let\Umathcode\XeTeXmathcode \let\Umathchardef\XeTeXmathchardef`. Perhaps the package should make a suitable test to avoid to break with older engines.